# How can I change the color of an icon without re-render (TextField loosing focus)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the package called `react-native-phone-input`, and when the phone number is changed it runs the function `this.updateInfo()` which updates the state. In my code, the icon color is dependent on the state and changes based on whether the phone number is valid. This works, however, when the state is changed, the screen re-renders and the keyboard is dismissed since the text field loses focus. Is there another way I can change the icons color? Or is there a way that I can keep the focus on the text field?

This is what I am referring to:

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Keyboard} from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import KeyboardAccessory from 'react-native-sticky-keyboard-accessory';
import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-input';

export default class PhoneLogin extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            valid: "",
            type: "",
            value: "",
            iconColor: "#D3D3D3",
        };

        this.updateInfo = this.updateInfo.bind(this);
    }

    updateInfo() {
        this.setState({
            valid: this.phone.isValidNumber(),
            type: this.phone.getNumberType(),
            value: this.phone.getValue().replace(/[- )(]/g,''),
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <PhoneInput
              ref={ref => {
                this.phone = ref;
              }}
              style={{height: 50, borderColor:'#44c0b9', borderBottomWidth:2}}
              onChangePhoneNumber={ (phone) => {this.updateInfo()} }
            />

            <KeyboardAccessory backgroundColor="#fff">
                <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', padding:10 }}>
                    <Icon
                        raised
                        reverse
                        color={(this.state.valid) ? "#44c0b9" : "#D3D3D3"}
                        name='arrow-right'
                        type='font-awesome'
                        onPress={ Keyboard.dismiss()}
                    />
                </View>
            </KeyboardAccessory>
          </View>
        );
    }

}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: "center",
      padding: 20,
      paddingTop: 60
    },
    info: {
      // width: 200,
      borderRadius: 5,
      backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
      padding: 10,
      marginTop: 20
    },
    button: {
      marginTop: 20,
      padding: 10
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onPress of your Icon you need to send an arrow function.

The Icon should be like this

```
<Icon 
    raised
    reverse
    color={(this.state.valid) ? "#44c0b9" : "#D3D3D3"
    name='arrow-right'
    type='font-awesome'
    onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
/>
```

The problem was the Keyboard.dismiss() was immediately running every time the component re-rendered thus dismissing your keyboard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh my!!! I have been stuck on this for days, I didn't realize it wasn't related to the `onChangePhonenumber()`. Thank you so much, you have no idea how dumb I feel!